# Which extension contains glProgramParameteriARB?

Tags: opengl

According to the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_geometry_shader4.txt) glProgramParameteriARB is a part of ARB_geometry_shader4. I have a graphics card which doesn't support ARB_geometry_shader4:

```
glxinfo | grep ARB_geometry_shader4
```

When I call `glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)glProgramParameteriARB)` I get a function address and everything works fine. Does it mean that the documentation has a bug ? How can I find an extension which contains glProgramParameteriARB ?

Comment: "*everything works fine*" What do you mean by that? Without ARB_geometry_shader4, there is nothing you can actually *use* that function to do. You can't write shaders against an extension that isn't implemented, and you can't call that function on programs that don't use the extension. So what "everything" are you referring to?

Comment: I can call glProgramParameteriARB for a geometry shader without receiving any GL errors. I have found the following topic: https://community.khronos.org/t/glprogramparameteri-entry-point-missing/60307 and I'm confused now.

Comment: "*I can call glProgramParameteriARB without receiving any GL errors.*" But you have no right to call that function. No extension supported by your implementation provides it. So how can you possibly be calling it?

Comment: @NicolBolas What about a topic mentioned above ? (*glProgramParameteriARB is from ARB_vertex_program*)

Comment: ... what about it? I don't understand what it is you're looking for. If you're not using the extensions that export it, you *should not care* what `glXGetProcAddress` returns for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glXGetProcAddress` can be called without having a current OpenGL context (unlike `wglGetProcAddress`). As such, the function pointers it returns are *independent* of the current context. Because of that, [it will return valid function pointers for *any* OpenGL function](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions#Linux_and_X-Windows). It uses delayed binding for this kind of stuff.

If you want to know whether you can use a function pointer, check the extension strings, not whether you get a valid pointer.